# inflating child and parent fragment layouts in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to figure out how to call a child fragment, have it inflate its view, replace a FrameLayout, then replace another FrameLayout with the fully inflated child and parent view. Then I'll be populating more data from the child fragment. How can I do this?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.parent_fragment_container, Child.newInstance("HIYA!"));
        ft.commit();

    }
    
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String arg0, Context arg1, AttributeSet arg2) {
        return super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }
    
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent_fragment_container" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Parent.java

```
public abstract class Parent extends Fragment {
    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();
    protected abstract String getTitle();
    
    protected View getRootView() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
    }
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        View parent = getRootView();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null, false);
        FrameLayout layout = parent.findViewById(R.id.child_fragment_container);
        layout.addView(view);
        
        return parent;
    }

}
```

parent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/testTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/child_fragment_container"
android:layout_below="@id/testTitle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Child.java

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    String msg;
    public Child() {}
        
    public static Child newInstance(String msg) {
        Child frag = new Child();
        
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("msg", msg);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        
        return frag;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        this.msg = getArguments().getString("msg");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("Child", "view created: "+view.toString());
        super.onViewCreated(view, bundle);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.child;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getTitle() {
        return "Child!";
    }
    
}
```

child.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/childTitle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="I'm the child!"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```